# Erro during migration run

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

Error during migration run:
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432.

I have no experience with postgres and database, but after running "yarn typeorm migration:run"

I get this error.

Comment: You are trying to connect to a postgres database on your computer (localhost/127.0.0.1) and the connection is being refused. Likely your postgres database isn't running locally or it's listening on another port.

Comment: Have you installed a local PosgreSQL server and configured your JavaScript framework with the appropriate credentials?